# Trying to put bundle in PATH

Tags: ruby, bash, path, rubygems, bundler

I'm working on a Ruby project that requires the use of a few gems. I'm a bit confused, since I thought I already had bundler installed on my Mac. I tried installing it just now and got the following error:

```
Leias-MacBook-Pro:spec leia$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.
```

I then tried using `--user-install`, a trick I picked up from browsing Stack Overflow.

```
Leias-MacBook-Pro:spec leia$ gem install bundler --user-install
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/leia/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin in your PATH, gem executables will not run.
Successfully installed bundler-2.0.2
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.0.2
Done installing documentation for bundler after 5 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Now, I kind of need the gem executables to run, so I opened my `.bash_profile` and dropped the following code in:

```
export PATH=/Users/leia/.gem/ruby/2.3.0/bin:$PATH
```

But no matter how I try to fix it, `bundle` still won't run. The gem I'm installing is rspec, and I definitely need to be able to run those executables. Am I doing something wrong here? I've tried to follow tutorials and Google similar issues, but I can't figure out what the problem is. Any pointers or suggestions?

Comment: Have you opened a new Terminal window after having changed your `.bash_profile`? What's the output of `echo $PATH`? Also, what version if macOS are you on (since macOS Catalina will use zsh by default instead of Bash)?

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).